# aws sagemker does not save model artifacts after training RLEstimator

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am training a RLEstimator with COACH toolkit and TENSORFLOW framework.

My code is based on [sagemaker docs](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v2.45.0/frameworks/rl/using_rl.html#id1):

```
import sagemaker
bucket = sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

from sagemaker.rl import RLEstimator, RLToolkit, RLFramework

instance_type = "ml.c5.2xlarge"
estimator = RLEstimator(source_dir='src',
                    entry_point="train-coach.py",
                    dependencies=["common/sagemaker_rl"],
                    toolkit=RLToolkit.COACH,
                    toolkit_version='0.11.1',
                    framework=RLFramework.TENSORFLOW,
                    role=role,
                    instance_count=1,
                    instance_type=instance_type,
                    output_path='s3://{}/'.format(bucket),
                    base_job_name='my-job-name')

estimator.fit()
```

Training is performed normally, the last lines in the output :

```
2021-06-15 06:10:02,088 sagemaker-containers INFO     Reporting training SUCCESS
2021-06-15 06:10:20 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2021-06-15 06:10:20 Completed - Training job completed
Training seconds: 136
Billable seconds: 136
```

But an attempt of deploying the model causes error:

```
predictor = estimator.deploy(instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                                initial_instance_count=1)
```

```
update_endpoint is a no-op in sagemaker>=2.
See: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2.html for details.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClientError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3b92cb4c3461> in <module>
      1 # Deploy my estimator to a SageMaker Endpoint and get a MXNetPredictor
      2 predictor = estimator.deploy(instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
----> 3                                 initial_instance_count=1)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in deploy(self, initial_instance_count, instance_type, serializer, deserializer, accelerator_type, endpoint_name, use_compiled_model, wait, model_name, kms_key, data_capture_config, tags, **kwargs)
    949             wait=wait,
    950             kms_key=kms_key,
--> 951             data_capture_config=data_capture_config,
    952         )
    953 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/tensorflow/model.py in deploy(self, initial_instance_count, instance_type, serializer, deserializer, accelerator_type, endpoint_name, tags, kms_key, wait, data_capture_config, update_endpoint)
    285             wait=wait,
    286             data_capture_config=data_capture_config,
--> 287             update_endpoint=update_endpoint,
    288         )
    289 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/model.py in deploy(self, initial_instance_count, instance_type, serializer, deserializer, accelerator_type, endpoint_name, tags, kms_key, wait, data_capture_config, **kwargs)
    761                 self._base_name = "-".join((self._base_name, compiled_model_suffix))
    762 
--> 763         self._create_sagemaker_model(instance_type, accelerator_type, tags)
    764         production_variant = sagemaker.production_variant(
    765             self.name, instance_type, initial_instance_count, accelerator_type=accelerator_type

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/model.py in _create_sagemaker_model(self, instance_type, accelerator_type, tags)
    329             vpc_config=self.vpc_config,
    330             enable_network_isolation=enable_network_isolation,
--> 331             tags=tags,
    332         )
    333 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in create_model(self, name, role, container_defs, vpc_config, enable_network_isolation, primary_container, tags)
   2554 
   2555         try:
-> 2556             self.sagemaker_client.create_model(**create_model_request)
   2557         except ClientError as e:
   2558             error_code = e.response["Error"]["Code"]

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    384                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    385             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 386             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    387 
    388         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    703             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    704             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 705             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    706         else:
    707             return parsed_response

ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Could not find model data at s3://<my-bucket>/sagemaker-rl-tensorflow-2021-06-15-06-05-55-347/output/model.tar.gz.
```

*/sagemaker-rl-tensorflow-2021-06-15-06-05-55-347/output/* folder contains *intermediate/* folder and *output.tar.gz*, but no *model.tar.gz* exists.

Why model artifacts are not saved during training?
How can I deploy my model to sagemeker endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

you need your code to save a model in `/opt/ml/model`.
At the end of training, SageMaker checks this location and uploads its content to S3.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check how many episodes that you're actually running. If your training printout doesn't contain any checkpoint logs that send to /opt/ml/model/data...etc... then your _save_tf_model function may not have any files to save. I had a similar issue where I only ran a single episode, and thus there were no checkpoints sending *.onnx files to my checkpoint directory.

Also, check line number 202 in your `sagemaker_rl.coach_launcher.py` file. In an older version I was using, it was missing the single line:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```